# Is Laravel Blade's $loop vairable available in Sage 9 views?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, wordpress-theming, laravel-blade

I'm experimenting with version 9 of the [Sage](https://github.com/roots/sage) WordPress starter theme which uses Laravel Blade as the template engine for constructing WP templates.

**My question is:** Does Sage 9 make [Blade's `$loop` variable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#the-loop-variable) available inside of loops in views?

For example, given the file `/my_theme/resources/views/archive.blade.php`:

```
1    @extends('layouts.app')
2
3    @section('content')
4      @include('partials.page-header')
5
6      @if (!have_posts())
7        <div class="alert alert-warning">
8          {{ __('Sorry, no results were found.', 'sage') }}
9        </div>
10        {!! get_search_form(false) !!}
11     @endif
12
13      @while (have_posts()) @php(the_post())
14
15      @include('partials.content-'.get_post_type())
16      @endwhile
17
18      {!! get_the_posts_navigation() !!}
19    @endsection
```

I would like to insert the following at line 14:

```
@if ($loop->first)
    // Do stuff on first iteration
@endif
```

However `$loop` is undefined.

Am I missing something or is this a limitation of Sage 9 at this time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$loop` variable available inside of `@foreach()` loops

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    @if ($loop->first)
       // This is the first iteration.
    @endif
@endforeach
```